# Oracle SQL developer Data modeler - composite keys

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I am creating entities and am trying to create composite keys as my primary keys in the data modeler.

However I am not able to do that as I dont know how to. The question is how do I create a composite key in  the data modeler.

Here is the snapshot:

[image: le]

here is the composite keys I am trying to create.

```
  Primary key TBD_ID + TBA_STAGE +  TBA_ASSIGNEEPNO  + TBA_STATUS   combination column, Foreign Key 
  TBD_ID
```

TBD_ID is the foreign key from T_BPM_Details and I want to add that to T_BPM_Assignee with the following colums to make a composite key as the primary key.

How do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle the PK checkbox for each of the columns.

[image]

Then if you preview the DDL generated, you can see -

```
CREATE TABLE composite_keys (
    key1         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    key2         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    key3         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    description  VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
)
LOGGING;

ALTER TABLE composite_keys
    ADD CONSTRAINT composite_keys_pk PRIMARY KEY ( key1,
                                                   key2,
                                                   key3 );
```